# how to sample from a dataset and get the indices of samples in initial dataset

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, sorting, sampling

I have a dataset A with a shape of (1000, 10).
I want to do sampling such that:

```
B = pd.DataFrame(A).sample(frac = 0.2)
```

how I can get the indices of A that contain B? or how I can sort A based on B to have those 200 rows of B at the beginning of A?

I have tried this code but I don't understand why it gives me an error

```
I = np.argwhere((A == B[:, None]).all(axis=2))[:, 1]
```

or this one

```
np.arange(A.shape[0])[np.isin(A,B).all(axis=1)]
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a boolean column in `A` that tells if row is in `B`
2. We can get rows in `B` with index by `A.index.isin(B.index)`
3. Sort with the new column and delete the column

```
# after defining A and B
# step 1, 2
A["isinB"] = A.index.isin(B.index)
# step 3 Trues go to front, Falses go to end
A.sort_values("isinB").drop("isinB", 1)
```